# Need to stop two loops from looping within a loop

Tags: java, jgrasp

So my program asks two questions, directions and miles. A user can enter an infinite input for direction and miles, but once the user is done he would simply type "Done" and the loop would break and show the message and the end. I can't get the loops to break need help. Also when a letter is typed for numOfMiles the program just ends. It's suppose to give the error message and reprompt but i can't seem to get that working.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class taxiService {

public static void main(String [] args) {

//Declare variables
double fareCharge = 5;
double totalMiles = 0;
double finalFareCharged = 0;
double finalxCoord = 0;
double finalyCoord = 0;
double numOfMiles = 0;
double finalCoord = 0;
String error = "Invalid data, please enter valid data!";

String directions = "";
boolean restart = true;
//Prompt for direction and miles
while(restart){ 

boolean reprompt = true;
boolean reprompt_SecondQuestion = true;

while (reprompt) {

   directions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a direction: ");
   if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("East")) {
      finalxCoord = finalxCoord + numOfMiles;
      reprompt = false;
      }
      else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("West")) {
               finalxCoord = finalxCoord - numOfMiles;
               reprompt = false;
               }
             else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("North")) {
                     finalyCoord = finalyCoord + numOfMiles;
                     reprompt = false;
                     }
                     else if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("South")) {
                             finalyCoord = finalyCoord - numOfMiles;
                             reprompt = false;
                             }
             else {
                 reprompt = true;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
             }    
        }
   while(reprompt_SecondQuestion)
   {
   numOfMiles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter distance in miles: "));
   if (numOfMiles > 0) {
        totalMiles += numOfMiles;  
        reprompt_SecondQuestion = false;
        }
         else {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
            }
    }

    //Prompt user to type "done"
    //Capture user input
    if(directions.equalsIgnoreCase("Done"))

    {
       //Display direction and miles to user
       restart = false;
       break;
    }
    else
    {
    }

}

finalFareCharged = fareCharge + ((numOfMiles / .25) * 2);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "miles: " + totalMiles + "\nDirection :" + directions + "\nFinal Charge: " + finalFareCharged + "\nCoordination: " + finalCoord);
}
}
```

I was able to use this to stop the looping problem

```
   while(done) {
   end = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Is this your destination?(YES/NO)");
    if (end.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
       restart = false;
       reprompt = false;
       reprompt_SecondQuestion = false;
       done = false;
       break;
        }
        else if (end.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
                 restart = true;
                 done = false;
                  }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
            done = true;
            }
}
```

i still got a problem with numOfMiles. if a letter is entered the program ends. it doesn't give the error message. i've added reprompt_SecondQestion = true; but no change.

Answer (score 1):

I would use labeled break statement (so the intention would be clear for  the future reader of the code). Here is the example which prints s0-1-2-3e:

```
...
System.out.print("s");
labelName:
while (true) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.print(i);
    if (i == 3) {
      break labelName;   // the "thing" you are looking for
    }
  }
  System.out.print("-");
}
System.out.print("e");
...
```

This means that you only need to add the label `label:` and condition statement:

```
if (directions.equalsIgnoreCase("Done")) {
  break label;
}
```

Your task now, is just to find a proper places to put the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition of your loop.  Something like this would suffice:

```
if(directions.equalsIgnoreCase("Done"))

{
   //Display direction and miles to user
   reprompt_SecondQuestion = false;
   reprompt = false;
   restart = false;
   break;
}
```

Also I cannot tell from the brackets where this block is located, if it is at all within the loop.  Please check, as proper formatting will save you hours.

Comment: I'm going to add a new loop asking if the user is done inputting since directions needs to be outputted in the showmessagedialog. I need it to say east, west, south, or north not done haha. Im going to add a new while(done) and see if it works.